# What's the point of the back piping operator

Tags: livescript

[LiveScript](http://livescript.net) features both the [forward and backward piping operator](http://livescript.net/#piping). The purpose of the forward piping is clear:
`[1, 2, 3] |> reverse |> tail |> sum` translates to and is much clearer than `sum(tail(reverse([1, 2, 3])));`.

However, the purpose of the backward piping is a mystery to me: `sum <| tail <| reverse <| [1, 2, 3]` is exactly the same as just `sum tail reverse [1, 2, 3]`, and as far as I can tell there's no difference in precedence.

So, what *is* the purpose of the `<|` operator in LiveScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful as a section, when you want to make a function that applies its argument to a value:

```
map (<| Math.PI), [(1 +), (2 -), (3 *), (4 /)]
```

It's also consistent; there's `|>` so you'd kinda expect the reverse to exist as well.